# Jquery Mobile back button won't work

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm making an PhoneGap app using Jquery Mobile, but I have a little problem with the navigation. I've added a back button on the header of every page using this code:

```
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">Atras</a>
```

The problem is that it works fine on my PC browser, but when I install it on the phone it just won't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you look at the PhoneGap jQM Docs?

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html

since it's a navigation problem maybe

> disabling the [pushState](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html) feature

as suggested. Also what version of jQM and PhoneGap are you using?

Could be related:

- http://encosia.com/why-phonegap-1-1-0-broke-jquery-mobiles-back-button/

Comment: Thank you! This worked great: [link](http://encosia.com/why-phonegap-1-1-0-broke-jquery-mobiles-back-button/)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the [Ripple emulator](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/download/ripple) ([Chrome version](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc)) to check if there's any JavaScript error?

Comment: FYI: The Ripple Chrome Extension will be discontinued on Feb 29th, 2012. Please visit our HTML5 site and download the new version of Ripple at the link below: https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/download/ripple Read all about the new release of Ripple here: http://devblog.blackberry.com/2011/12/ripple-beta-refresh-download/

Comment: You're welcome.. and thanks for the information about the Chrome extension.. I didn't know that..